# Remove all text between 2 sentences in regex

Tags: sql, regex

I going crazry with regex.

I need to extract a words between `FROM` and `WHERE` in this syntax:

```
SELECT IDClient, Client FROM Client WHERE IDClient = 1 GROUP BY IDClient, Client ORDER BY IDClient
```

result = Client

How can I resolve this using regular expressions?

Comment: The title doesn't match your request, do you want to remove or extract text ?

Answer (score 2):

/FROM (.*) WHERE/i

Comment: That will return the FROM and WHERE as part of the match which is not what was asked

Comment: @rrr You can extract `$1` from the match - granted sql regex engine supports that.

Comment: @rrrr OP asked how to get the string between and if you look at the match closely, then you will notice index 0 points to the whole match and match 1 will only show the part in paranthesis. Sadly the question is not very specific so no one knows with what you're performing the regex matching/replacing on that mysql-query.. Any further answer would be wild guessing! And the used tags are misleading…

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=FROM\s+).*(?=\s+WHERE)
```

That uses a look behind and a lookahead to get what is between FROM and WHERE, and can be modified depending on whether you want the whitespace or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/), it's not too hard to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this online regular expression builder:

- http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Or try the tutorials at:

- regular-expressions dot info